# What are the Shabar mantras?

Tags: mantras, hanuman, etymology

There are many mantras dedicated to Hanuman. Some popular choki mantras are "Ekamukhi", "Panchmukhi", "Ekadhashamukhi" etc. Recently I've heard/remembered about Shabar mantras (शाबर मंत्र) which in Hindi. They're believed very powerful with instant effect. So, I want to know about:

- What are Shabar mantra?
- Why are they called "Shabar"?
- Who has written them?

Are Shabar Mantras written/dedicated to Hanuman only or there are Shabar mantras for other deities also?

Answer (score 8):

As you may have noticed that these mantras are quite different from Vedic mantras or those contained in other Hindu Shastras although they are also (mostly)related to Vedic Deities only.

They use mostly spoken languages as opposed to sanskrit and also at times the words used in them are such that the mantras look completely meaningless.

For example, given below is one such mantra dedicated to Goddess Saraswati(which is supposedly for removal of negative energy,but don't just chant this of course):

> Sarasvatī gāḍī sunna kā dīyā rupē kī bātī guṇa bātī bātī. Aṅkīnī,
>   ḍaṅkīnī, śaṅkhinī, jādū ṭōnā mērī bhavānī isī ghaḍī yahām̐ sē nikala
>   jāya, mērī a̔āna mērē gurū kī a̔āna īśvara gaurā pārvatī mahādēva kī
>   duhā'ī.

But they do make good use of the Pranava(Om) .

For example,the following is a mantra for the Natha sampradaya Guru Gorakshnath:

> Satya Naam AAdesh Guru Ka Om Guru Gorokhnathaya Namaha

And,following is a shabar mantra for Goddess Durga:

> Om Ath Bhuji Ambika Ek Naam Omkar Khat Darshan Tribhuvan Mein Panch
>   Pandava Saat Deep Chaar Khoont Nau Khand Mein Chnada Suraj Do Praman
>   Haath Jodh Binti Karoon Mam Karoo Kalyan.

They are related to the [Natha Sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorakshanath).

The propounder of such mantras are  the Natha Sampradaya Gurus like Gorakshnath,[Matsyendranath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsyendranath) etc.

All of them are descendants of the first Guru or Adi Natha or Lord Shiva.

The famous Yoga treatise "[Hatha Yoga Pradipika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_Yoga_Pradipika)" lists few Siddha Gurus of this Parampara among whom one is called Shabar.

I assume that the mantras are named after him.

> [image]
>   Śrīādināthamatsyendra**śāvar**ānandabhairavāh
>   chaurangghīmīnaghorakshavirūpākshabileśayāh
>
> Sri Âdinâtha (Śiva), matsyendra, Nâtha, **Sâbar**, Anand, Bhairava,
>   Chaurangi, mîna nâtha, Goraksanâtha, Virupâksa, Bileśaya.

According to some web pages these mantras are auto-energized or siddha but some others claim that a regular diksha(initiation) is needed from a proper Guru before chanting them.

It is also believed that these mantras are more effective in Kali Yuga than any other mantras.

Comment: I vaugely remember that Tulsidas mentions about Shabar Mantra in Bala Kanda of Ramcharitmanas.. but I'm not sure where exactly it is...

Comment: @Tezz Shlok 3, Doha 15, Balkanda, Shri Ramcharitmanas. कलि बिलोकि जग हित हर गिरिजा । साबर मंत्र जाल जिन्ह सिरिजा ⁠।⁠। अनमिल आखर अरथ न जापू । प्रगट प्रभाउ महेस प्रताप। It Tulsi ji says that Shiv ji created Shaabar mantra for kaliyug. It's meaning is unclear, words don't rhyme and jap is also not done. Yet they are powerful because of blessings of Shiv ji.

Comment: Tulsi ji says this in the context of his own writing which is in colloquial language. He seeks blessings from Shiv ji to make his work powerful as well, just like he did for Shabar mantra