# Are Shabar Mantras really auto-energised?

Tags: mantras, guru, nath

I myself answered a question on the so-called "Shabar Mantras" [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16673/what-are-the-shabar-mantras).

[This](http://www.shabarmantraonline.com/) webpage claims that these mantras are auto energized or Siddha so to speak.

> A shabar mantra is quite different from a classical or Vedic mantra.
>   One needs to attain siddhi to use a Vedic mantra but it is nothing
>   like this in case of a shabar mantra. **Shabar mantras as auto-energized**
>   and can be used even by a common man easily to bring his wishes true.

Is that true?

Also does that  imply that for these mantras upadesha from Guru(initiation) is not needed?

Comment: Most of the Shabara mantras were created by Guru Gorakhnath (and his Shishyas).... so we won't find informations about Shabara mantra in scriptures... Do you want information from works of Guru Gorakhnath like Goraksha Shatakam, Natha Yogi books etc... ?

Comment: @Tezz Yes that will do..I know that we can't find any info on these mantras in our traditional scriptures..Actually i am planning to buy some books on them as well..

Comment: @Rickross better to try and see the result. But as far as i know they do have utmost importance of guru and they believe mantra work only if it is gurumukhi

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I in fact tried a few of them during my morning Japa sessions already..The results are different to start with..but i can't be sure of the reasons..Also i too feel that these mantras will require initiation becoz they too are part of a Sampradaya..I am planning to buy some books on them..just unsure which books are a good buy..

Comment: @Rickross Did you find any quality books?

Comment: @chhatra No I have not found any.