# Shabar Mantras and their potency

Tags: tantra, dhumavati, shabara, abhichara, shabar

Shabar Mantras more potent than sanskrit tantric mantras for kamya prayogas? Dhumavati practice against enemy is available in both sanskrit originals and shabara vidya. Which of the two would be more potent?

Comment: Shabar mantras are potent in the sense that they do not have locks (kilakas) and they give results immediately (not the case with usual mantras). But there can be risks in using these mantras if not done under someone's supervision.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17510/4732

Comment: indeed but i was curious...if someone does some amya prayogas using shabar vs sanskrit mantras, which would yield powerful results? or is it dependent on the tapobal of sadhakas?

Comment: Shabar mantras are meant to work very fast .. for Sanskrit mantras before applying one has to make them Siddha first and this process is time consuming. But there can be risk in using Shabar mantras

Comment: thank u so much......do you happen to know whether shabar kriyas have an authentic parampara of siddhas from old times?

Comment: It must have paramparas through which the mantras and related knowledge have passed down from Lord Shiva from whom everything started.